# How to use Android date picked using detox?

Tags: detox

I am trying to test [react-native-modal-datetime-picker](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) and select a date for android, (later I will need for IOS).
I am unable tho to pick a date currently.
I found a solution for Appium using espresso[(See this)](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-send-year-month-and-day-to-android-date-picker/25307), But this solution uses findelementByID for getting the android element id which is unavailable using detox(detox `by.id` gets the android element tag and not id from what I saw).
This is how I got the ID of the element I want to test using android studio:
[image]

While using detox, is there any alternative for testing an android date picker? or a way to get an android element id?

Comment: Do the subviews have tags set?

Comment: They do not have tags, only id, and I guess this is why appium approaching this issue using id selector